# How to create a generic class using CodeDOM whose generic parameter is a type that I created?

Tags: c#, codedom

I have a class that I created using CodeDOM:

```
CodeTypeDeclaration some_class = new CodeTypeDeclaration("SomeClass");
// ... properties and methods creation elided
```

I want to create a List of the "SomeClass" type. However, I can't seem to do so:

```
var list_type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof (List<>).Name, ??? some_class ???);
var member_field = new CodeMemberField(list_type, field_name)
                                      {
                                               Attributes = MemberAttributes.Private,
                                      };
```

CodeTypeReference doesn't accept a `CodeTypeDeclaration`, which is what I need. What can I do? I **don't** want to pass the class name as a string, since this could lead to errors.

Comment: How would passing the Name property of the type declaration be any different from using the name property of typeof(List<>) ?

Comment: @tyranid `typeof(list<>)` relies on reflection to retrieve the name; but I see your point... I could use list_type.Name, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't. There doesn't seem to be any way to create a `CodeTypeReference` from a `CodeTypeDeclaration`. I *think* that's because `CodeTypeDeclaration` does not know what namespace it's in, so there is no safe way to do that.

On the other hand, when creating a `CodeTypeReference` to generic type, you don't need to use the name of the generic type:

```
var listType = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(List<>));
listType.TypeArguments.Add(typeof(int));
```

Comment: The problem is that I'd like to do `TypeArguments.Add(my_type_declaration)`. I think I will have to do with using the name of my type anyway. Thanks!

Comment: My issue was that XSD elements were generated as Array's instead of List<>.
This fixed my problem! Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

The chosen answer didn't work for me for whatever reason, but this did:

`var listType = new CodeTypeReference("List", new[] { new CodeTypeReference(typeof(int)) });`

[See documentation here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wf5z110(v=vs.110).aspx)